# Using Reflections: how to test method

Tags: java, testing, reflection

I have been looking at Reflections lately in java and I have come up with a simple example

Reflection.java

```
 import java.lang.reflect.*;

  public class Reflection{
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     try {
       Class cls = Class.forName("Method");

        Method methlist[] 
          = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methlist.length;
           i++) {  
           Method m = methlist[i];
           System.out.println("name 
             = " + m.getName());
           System.out.println("decl class = " +
                          m.getDeclaringClass());
           Class pvec[] = m.getParameterTypes();
           for (int j = 0; j < pvec.length; j++)
              System.out.println("
               param #" + j + " " + pvec[j]);
           Class evec[] = m.getExceptionTypes();
           for (int j = 0; j < evec.length; j++)
              System.out.println("exc #" + j 
                + " " + evec[j]);
           System.out.println("return type = " +
                              m.getReturnType());
           System.out.println("-----");
        }
     }
     catch (Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
     }
  }
 }
```

Method.java

```
 public class Method {
  private int f1(
   Object p, int x) throws NullPointerException
  {
     if (p == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
     return x;
  }
```

From the above example i am able to return all the information from `Method.java` which looks like this

```
name = f1
decl class = class Method
param #0 class java.lang.Object
param #1 int
exc #0 class java.lang.NullPointerException
return type = int
-----
name = main
decl class = class method1
param #0 class [Ljava.lang.String;
return type = void
-----
```

But my question is, is there a way to test `Method.java` from `Reflection.java` with something like

```
int x = cls.getMethod("f1", Object = anObject, Integer.TYPE = 2 )
System.out.println(x);
```

And the console should print out 2 because f1 was passed an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Method` and *invoke* the private method `f1` with the two parameters. It will return an object. There are a couple of pitfalls in your code, but here's a working solution (Note: I renamed your class `Method` to `MyMethod` to avoid a name clash:

```
Method f1Method = MyMethod.class.getDeclaredMethod("f1", Object.class, int.class);
f1Method.setAccessible(true);
int result = (Integer) f1Method.invoke(new MyMethod(), 
                           new Object[]{new Object(), 2});
System.out.println(result);
```

- The method is *private* so you need to get the *declared* method and make it accessible
- The method is not static so we need an instance of MyMethod to invoke the method
- We pass and receive a java primitive type. `int.class` is allowed. JavaDoc tells us, that *if the value has a primitive type, it is first appropriately wrapped in an object*. So we'll receive an instance of `Integer`.

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly and very well explained as well, understand it a lot better now... thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Javadoc for `java.lang.reflect.Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html). You want the method `invoke()`;

```
Method m = ...
Object result = m.invoke(objectToCallMethodOn, firstArgument, secondArgument);
int x = ((Integer) result).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the `Method` class I refer to is the [`Method` class in the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), not the one in your example

You are already capable of finding the `Method` from the `Class` object. You can now use the [`Method#invoke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method to invoke the method on a certain object